# variable, needed explaination on [1] and [2]

Tags: php

I need an explaination about this coding:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query); 
$projectinfo= mysqli_fetch_row($result); 
$projectname= $projectinfo[0];
 $projectID= $projectinfo[1];
```

What i wanted to know : 
what does this line means ?

```
$projectname= $projectinfo[0];
 $projectID= $projectinfo[1];
```

Why there is [0],[1]

Comment: First, $projectinfo is an array which contains two elements 0 have the project name and 1 have to project id

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_row()` returns an array containing the next row of results of the query.

`$projectinfo[0]` is the first element of this array, `$projectinfo[1]` is the second element of this array. These correspond to the first and second columns selected by the SQL query. The query might be something like:

```
SELECT name, id
FROM projects
```